# change category_id with a selector ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, categories, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to save a post with an optional category. But every time I create a new post, the post is created with category_id "1".

view

```
<%= form_for(@posts) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %>
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select a category' %>
<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
```

controller

```
def new
@posts = Post.new
end

def create
@category = Category.find_by(params[:category_id])
@posts = @category.posts.build(post_params)
@posts.save
redirect_to :back
end

private
def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title)
end
```

category - model

```
has_many :posts
```

post - model

```
belongs_to :categorys
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your `new` action as well.

Comment: Okay. I have changed it.

Comment: Your structure is way off. You are overriding `category_id` because you're finding the `Category` using `params[:category_id]` in your create action, but your create path for `posts` should not contain the `:category_id`. It should simply be `POST /posts`. What does your `routes.rb` look like? You also need to permit the `category_id` param -- `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :category_id)`

Comment: I have added category_id in the params.require.. I have this in my routes resources :posts, :categorys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed

`@category = Category.find_by(params[:category_id])`

and changed

`@posts = @category.posts.build(post_params)`

to

`@posts = Post.create(post_params)`

and it worked. Thanks a lot for the help.